# Collecting results from celery worker with asyncio

Tags: python, celery, python-asyncio

I am having a Python application which offloads a number of processing work to a set of celery workers. The main application has to then wait for results from these workers. As and when result is available from a worker, the main application will process the results and will schedule more workers to be executed.

I would like the main application to run in a non-blocking fashion. As of now, I am having a polling function to see whether results are available from any of the workers.

I am looking at the possibility of using asyncio get notification about result availability so that I can avoid the polling. But, I could not find any information on how to do this.

Any pointers on this will be highly appreciated.

PS: I know with gevent, I can avoid the polling. However, I am on python3.4 and hence would prefer to avoid gevent and use asyncio.

Comment: Have a look at [asyncio.as_completed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-functions).

Comment: AFAIK there is no asyncio redis client, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You must be looking for   `asyncio.as_completed(coros)`. It yields as and when the results are ready from different coroutines. It returns an iterator which yields - in the order in which they are completed. You might also want to see how it differs from `asyncio.gather(*coros)` which returns once everything submitted to it has fininshed

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.coroutines import coroutine


@coroutine
def some_work(x, y):
    print("doing some background work")
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return x * y


@coroutine
def some_other_work(x, y):
    print("doing some background other work")
    yield from asyncio.sleep(3.0)
    return x + y


@coroutine
def as_when_completed():
    # give me results as and when they are ready
    coros = [some_work(2, 3), some_other_work(2, 3)]
    for futures in asyncio.as_completed(coros):
        res = yield from futures
        print(res)


@coroutine
def when_all_completed():
    # when everything is complete
    coros = [some_work(2, 3), some_other_work(2, 3)]
    results = yield from asyncio.gather(*coros)
    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    # loop.run_until_complete(when_all_completed())
    loop.run_until_complete(as_when_completed())
```

Answer (score 2):

I implement `on_finish` function of `celery worker` to publish a message to `redis`

then in the main app uses `aioredis` to subscribe the channel, once got notified, the result is ready

Comment: THANKS!!! I figured out how to update an instance variable from the class where I was launching celery task thanks to you! you sir made my day